# Is there a naming convention for the left child of a right child (and vice versa)?

Tags: binary-trees

That is, the right child of a left child, or the left child of a right child. The best that I can come up with is the "opposing child" but I was wondering if anyone has come across an existing naming convention for this.

Comment: Minor comment on the form: I believe that, ideally, the question should stand on its own and not refer to the title

Comment: If you are interested in terms for a broader set of relationships, you might want to consider modifying [kinship terms from anthropology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinship_terminology#Abbreviations_for_genealogical_relationships).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'sibling' (or 'brother'/'sister' if you prefer to gender the vertices). It's somewhat commonly used, but you may want to redefine it quickly when using it extensively.

NB: this terminology can be used for non-binary tree, the *sibling* of a vertex is any other vertex with the same parent/father.

While you may want to find a more reliable source, Wikipedia agrees with me at the moment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure